# Update screen in Cocoa/Objective C following button press

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Newbie Objective C/Cocoa question: I have an application with some data entry fields and a "do it" button. When the button is pressed, some computation takes place and output data is displayed in a table view and some text fields in the same window. What I'd like is that when the button is pressed that the text fields and the table view are both cleared while the computation takes place.

I've tried making the appropriate calls as the first few statements of the action routine for the button press, but that doesn't work. I would imagine that the runtimes don't get called to do the screen update until after my action routine is finished.

Is there a simple way to do what I want to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct about the screen updates not taking place until after your routine finishes. Most drawing to the screen is queued to improve performance.

When you change the value in an `NSTextField`, it knows to call `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]` in order to queue its need for redrawing. If you want to force it to display, you can call `[textField display]`. (Note that calling `[textField setNeedsDisplay:YES]` will not cause immediate display). Things get a bit more difficult with an `NSTableView`, as this `-display` method is unlikely to work for it.

While you could create a secondary thread to do your processing, that would create a lot of complexity that may not be worth it. You might consider using `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` to begin your processing routine rather than calling it directly.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
  [textField setStringValue:@""];
  [tableView reloadData];
  // instead of doing the following:
  // [self processData:nil];
  // do
  [self performSelector:@selector(processData:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}

- (void)processData:(id)sender {
  // process the data

  [textField setStringValue:@"the results"];
  [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Using `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is different than calling the method directly, as it causes the method to be called not immediately, but scheduled to be called "ASAP". In many cases, your app will be able to squeeze in the updates to the UI before it can get to performing that computation method. If testing reveals this to be the case, then you can avoid having to go to the trouble of creating a secondary thread to do the processing.

Comment: This worked great, thanks, except that I needed a delay of 0.1. I learned a lot from all of these answers and wish I could accept more than one.

Answer (score 5):

You imagine correctly.

The usual way to do this sort of thing is to use NSObject's [`performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorInBackground%3awithObject%3a) to start the heavy calculation in the background. Then once the background code finishes doing its work, use [`performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a) to call another selector on the main thread to update the UI (remember, UI calls may only be done from the main thread).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force updating screen then call **setNeedsDisplay** from your UIView.

Comment: That has the same problem. I can (and did) call setNeedsDisplay for the relevant controls inside the button action routine, but again I don't think the screen update actually happens until the action routine returns.

Comment: As I mentioned, the textField already sets itself as needing display. You would need to force it to display using `-display`.

Comment: If you do heavy calculation then you should do it (calculation) in the other thread (do in background or create new thread or NSOperation). All update screen tasks are done in the main thread. After the calculation is done you can show the result by calling performSelectorOnMainThread

Answer (score 1):

> I would imagine that the runtimes
>   don't get called to do the screen
>   update until after my action routine
>   is finished.

Bingo.  Your button's action method is called on the main thread, which is the same thread that is responsible for updating the user-interface.  So the interface will not update until after your action method returns.

To get around this, you can split your action method into two parts.  The first part makes the calls to clear your previous view and set whatever new state you want to use for rendering.  The second part does the new calculations, and is moved to its own method.  Then, at the end of the first part, add something roughly like:

`[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myActionSecondPart) withObject:nil];`

...to run the computation part in the background.  Then your UI will update while the computation runs.